# jQuery array values get into select option values?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

i have some data into `sort` array i want get each value from array in to Select option value. how can i get values from Array and make output like **HTML**? I would be grateful for any help.

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        new Sortable(drop, {
            onChange: function (event, ui) {
                sort = ["67", "66", "65", "64", "63"];
                $('#drop').children().each(function () {
                    $('#id_articles').append(`<option value="${sort}" selected=""></option>`);
                    sort.push($(this).data('pk'))
                    console.log(sort)
                });
            },
        })
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="articles" required="" id="id_articles" multiple>
    <option value="67" selected=""></option>
    <option value="66" selected=""></option>
    <option value="65" selected=""></option>
    <option value="64" selected=""></option>
    <option value="63" selected=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: You want to generate the HTML you wrote?

Comment: What is the situation at the beginning, what is the situation at the end and what causes the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution of appending options into select box...

```js
sort = ["67", "66", "65", "64", "63"];
$.each(sort, function (index, value) {
    $('#id_articles').append($('<option/>', { 
        value: value,
        text : value 
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="articles" required="" id="id_articles" multiple>
</select>
```